# Refractive index values of the solution less than that of the solvent. Why does that happen?

Tags: experimental-physics, refraction, physical-chemistry, non-linear-optics

I have been doing an experiment for finding the third-order nonlinear susceptibilties of organic molecules using Degenerate Four-Wave Mixing (DFWM) at femtosecond regime. For the calculation of the third-order susceptibility ($\chi_3$) using the intensities of the input beams (two pumps and a probe) and the measured intensity of the diffracted beam (signal) are required.

The samples are diluted with chloroform to reduce the concentration to 0.05 mmol to avoid scattering of the signal beam. However, the formula requires me to enter the refractive index value of the solution. Hence, I measured the refractive index of the solutions using spectrophotometric method which gives me refractive index values at third decimal precision.

After calculations, I found that the refractive index values of some of the solutions were less than that of the solvent (Chloroform) while some were higher than the solvent. The variation is there in second decimal points as the value varies from 1.42 to 1.48 while the reported value of refractive index of chloroform is 1.44.

What is/are the cause/causes of these variations?

NOTE: The wavelength used both for nonlinear studies and the refractive index measurements are the same (i.e. 532 nm). Also, both the experiments were done at a temperature controlled environment.

Comment: How does the solution affect the density of the chloroform?

Comment: @my2cts Chloroform is the solvent and the solute is the organic molecules. Logically, the organic molecules should add to the density of the solution. And since, the density is increasing, the refractive index should also increase. I have not done any experiment as to see the effect to the density as such.

Comment: @FellowTraveller In a more precise manner, "Why is refractive index values of the solution less than that of the solvent even though the solute is adding onto the total density of the solution? Ideally, more the density, more should be the refractive index."

Comment: It is not logical that adding the solute will increase the density. If you just average the densities if solvent and solute you are missing their interaction. It is physical.

Comment: See https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/density-aqueous-solution-organic-sugar-alcohol-concentration-d_1954.html for data to compare with average density.

Comment: Where the solution just different in conc or you are measuring with different molecules? Plus interaction, as already point out above.

Comment: @Alchimista the concentration is constant but the solute molecules are different.

Comment: The variation is quite small and is almost centred on the refractive index of pure solvent. In [refractive index of protein solutions](https://www.jbc.org/content/7/5/359.full.pdf) on p 362 the variation is in the 3rd decimal place for concentrations of 0-5%. I suggest the explanation is due to error in your measurements.

Comment: We calibrate the setup every time before a measurement for some reference samples like water, methanol, chloroform etc. The variations are seen in the third decimal and each time the second decimal remains constant. In the above mentioned case, the variations are seen in second decimal. Errors can come only in third decimal because of the precision of the experiment. @sammygerbil

Comment: Then It is possible that togheter with the reason already pointed out by my2cts the effect is intrinsically linked to the solutes, ie molecule with lower refr index. Though for the same reason above I am not sure we think "additively".